# inet 192.168.0.214/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global secondary enp3s0

Tags: networking

Please advise what is going on here. I configured (in /etc/netplan) a static address as above and now I'm being told it's a "secondary address" with 192.168.0.199 (dchp obtained) being the primary.

If the primary config file in /etc/netplan tells the system a static ip has been assigned, can you please ensure that it over-rides whatever else is contradicting this setting. Or alternatively make clear in documentation ALL the files which need to be changed in order to set a static ip. I'm seeing above I need to go check for yaml files in /lib/netplan and /run/netplan. Oh for goodness sake, why not go back to good old simple /etc/network/interfaces.

```
neilp@Lubuntu:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
cat: /etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory

neilp@Lubuntu:~$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

neilp@Lubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for neilp: 
  *-network:0               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
       logical name: enp0s3
       version: 02
       serial: 08:00:27:8d:2c:2a
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm pcix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.0.101 latency=64 link=yes mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:f0200000-f021ffff ioport:d020(size=8)
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 8
       bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
       logical name: enp0s8
       version: 02
       serial: 08:00:27:a6:57:79
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm pcix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI duplex=full latency=64 link=yes mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:16 memory:f0820000-f083ffff ioport:d240(size=8)
```

Comment: Are you running a Desktop or Server installation? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit].

Comment: Your config is using Network Manager.  That overrides `/etc/network/interfaces` and any other configuration.  Which suggests you're using a Desktop installation or such, something that uses Network Manager.  Which in turn overrides any configuration you enter yourself in `netplan` or `/etc/network/interfaces`.  This isn't a Netplan or `/etc/network/interfaces` problem - this is user error in misunderstanding what is actually handling your network configuration - Network Manager (so nmcli on the command line or the GUI network manager applet if on a Desktop)

Comment: @heynnema I gave up on netplan and went back to network manager. Configured static ips on both interfaces but both are being ignored (same as with netplan) and the system reverts to a default auto dhcp on the first interface and ignores the second altogether.

Comment: @heynnema I'm running Lubuntu 20.04 VM under Virtual Box.

Comment: There's an auto-generated file enp0s3.yaml in /run/netplan and it just overrides the static ip settings I configure under network-manager gui.